# Usage of "while"

Tags: grammar

> "She was telling me about her exploits while travelling around Africa."

The sentence usually means "She did something during her trip to Africa, and she was telling me about it."

Can it also be interpreted as "While we were traveling around Africa, she told me about her exploits"?

Comment: Actually your second sentence is a more common interpretation than the first.

Comment: Most people would interpret it in the manner of your first sentence.  Everything after "her" is what she was telling you about.

Comment: @Chenmunka That depends _entirely_ on what comes after. “She was telling me about her exploits while cleaning the kitchen cupboard” would be almost universally be interpreted in the second manner—few would presume many exploits to take place during the cleaning of a kitchen cupboard.

Answer (score 1):

Both interpretations are possible, the sentence is grammatically ambiguous. However, people will usually express the second meaning by saying something like

> ... while *we were* travelling around Africa.

Without that, it would be normal to assume the first interpretation.

In addition, the listener may know whether or not the speaker travelled with her in Africa, and that will clarify which meaning makes more sense.

Comment: Or just replace _while_ with _when_, in which case it becomes ambiguous: “She was telling me about her exploits when travelling through Africa”. Even deleting it altogether makes it more (though not entirely) unambiguous: “She was telling me about her exploits travelling through Africa”.

Answer (score 0):

Both your interpretations are correct. Your second interpretation is more common than the first but it doesn't mean it is more correct than the first.

Answer (score 0):

Without further context, the sentence could mean either, but as the sentence is written, I would lean towards: "She did something during her trip to Africa, and she was telling me about it."

To convey "While we were traveling around Africa, she told me about her exploits", I would add a comma to the sentence: "She was telling me about her exploits, while travelling around Africa."

But both alternatives are clearer than the original sentence.